# Maven Site, set TeamCity as ciManagement system?

Tags: teamcity, maven-site-plugin

Is there a way I can configure my Maven site to display TeamCity as the CI Management tool?  I've tried specifying "TeamCity", "Team City" and even "http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/", but the resulting Maven site simply displays

```
"This project uses Continuous Integration System."
```

It seems that this part of the POM only recognises particular keywords, such as Jenkins or Continuum - is that correct?  Is there a special keyword for Team City, or another way I can force it to display the name?

Answer (score 0):

Reference: https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Continuous_Integration_Management

Try this:

```
<project>
  ...
  <ciManagement>
    <system>TeamCity</system>
    <url>http://path.to.your/host</url>
  </ciManagement>
</project>
```

Comment: Nope, still results in same default message.